# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: module1/MyNewJava: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java

Tried to run the MyNewJava.java file in Module 1 as applet. I am on OSX 10.10.5 and have Java SE 8 [1.80.0_60] as my default JRE. Any Idea whats going on?

Comment: I suspect you're not *actually* running in the JRE you think you are...

Comment: How did you try to run this `MyNewJava.java` file from this `Module 1`? From the command line or via in IDE?

Comment: This means your code is running with an older JRE than what you've compiled the code with. It's not running on JRE 8, despite that being your default JRE.

Comment: thanks, I think you are right,  it is an older JRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MyNewJava.java` file was compiled in a later version of Java than the Applet's runtime environment or JRE.

Comment: Right click on JRE System Library and select Properties.

In the menu select Alternate JRE and select Java SE 8 [1.8.0_60] and press OK. fixed the issue.